# to insert forecast corresponding to its checkbox into my sql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm inserting index using checkbox and forecast using select option. I want to insert index and its corresponding forecast into database. My problem is this if I check index for one station and forecast for another it is also inserted into database. Please help me !!
my php code for user  side is this

```
   <?php
   $stn=array(lucknow,delhi,sitapur);
   $index=array(226020,110001,261203);
   $fct=array(a,b,c);

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($index); $i++) 
{
?>                   
<input type= "checkbox"  name="stn1[]" value="<? echo $index[$i];?>"><strong>
                              <? echo $stn[$i];?></strong></br>
<select name="forecast[]">
<?php

 echo "<option disabled selected> -- Select an option -- </option>";
 foreach($fct as $forecast)
  {
   echo"<option>$forecast</option>";
  }

?>

                          </select>

<?php
}
 ?
     <input type="Submit" value= "Submit" class="style3" name="Submit">
```

Server side php code is this

```
  $station1=$_POST['stn1'];
 $forecast1=$_POST['forecast'];
if (sizeof($station1)=="0" or sizeof($forecast1)=="0" or sizeof($station1)!  =sizeof($forecast1)) {
 die('<h1 align= center><font color=red>Either You have not selected station or forecast. </p> !!! Please select station and its corresponding forecast carefully</font><h1>');
 } else {
 if ($_POST['Submit']=="Submit"){ 
 for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($station1); $i++)
 { 
 // some my sql command to insert data into database
}
 }   
  echo "<h1 align= center><font color=green> Record is inserted       successfully</font></h1>";
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by index? it's the index of the forecast? which is the relationship between these two?

Comment: index is defined as variable and i'm trying to store index and its corresponding forecast in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Its because all three of your checkboxes and selects have the same name.
Instead of `name="forecast[]"` use `name=<? echo $stn[$i];?>`, Then on the server side check if the select tag's name value matches the checkbox name value.

Comment: when I'm using name as suggested in places of forecast[] then it doesn't works because i'm calling forecast as an array in server side php code